# Pandas: rowwise multiplication of two dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multiplication

I have two dataframes; A contains allocation fractions and B contains hourly volumes. To get the right volume for each bus for a given hour, I need to multiply A with each row of dataframe B. For a given hour (x), this would be a simple multiplication of `A * B.loc[x]`.

```
A =       col_a  col_b  col_c   col_d   col_e               
     0    0.0    0.0    0.0     0.0     1.0
     1    0.0    0.0    1.0     0.0     0.0
     2    0.0    1.0    0.0     0.5     0.0
     3    0.5    0.0    0.0     0.5     0.0
     4    0.5    0.0    0.0     0.0     0.0
```

```
B =     col_a   col_b   col_c   col_d   col_e
    0   12881   598     154     180     0.0 
    1   12881   680     154     180     0.0
    2   11617   806     154     180     0.0
    3   12991   100     154     180     0.0
```

However, I want to do this multiplication for each hour at once and create a large multiindex dataframe C.

```
C =          col_a   col_b  col_c  col_d  col_e
    hr  bus                     
    0   0    0.0     0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0
        1    0.0     0.0    154.0  0.0   0.0
        2    0.0     598.0  0.0    90.0  0.0
        3    6440.5  0.0    0.0    90.0  0.0
        4    6440.5  0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0
    1   0    0.0     0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0
        1    0.0     0.0    154.0  0.0   0.0
        2    0.0     680.0  0.0    90.0  0.0
```

I managed to create this dataframe with a list operation and overwriting the index of the resulting dataframe. I would not consider this a very good practice and wonder if there's a better approach that doesn't require an overwrite of the index?

```
dfs = [A.mul(B.loc[i]) for i in B.index]
C = pandas.concat(dfs)

C.index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_product([B.index, A.index], names=['hr', 'bus'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First "replicate" *B* DataFrame, reformatting the index:

```
BB = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(B.values, A.index.size, axis=0), columns=B.columns,
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product((B.index, A.index), names=['hr', 'bus']))
```

Then compute the result:

```
result = A.mul(BB, level=1)
```

The result is:

```
         col_a  col_b  col_c  col_d  col_e
hr bus                                    
0  0       0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
   1       0.0    0.0  154.0    0.0    0.0
   2       0.0  598.0    0.0   90.0    0.0
   3    6440.5    0.0    0.0   90.0    0.0
   4    6440.5    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
1  0       0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
   1       0.0    0.0  154.0    0.0    0.0
   2       0.0  680.0    0.0   90.0    0.0
   3    6440.5    0.0    0.0   90.0    0.0
   4    6440.5    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
2  0       0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
   1       0.0    0.0  154.0    0.0    0.0
   2       0.0  806.0    0.0   90.0    0.0
   3    5808.5    0.0    0.0   90.0    0.0
   4    5808.5    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
3  0       0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
   1       0.0    0.0  154.0    0.0    0.0
   2       0.0  100.0    0.0   90.0    0.0
   3    6495.5    0.0    0.0   90.0    0.0
   4    6495.5    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
```